# Where are the libraries/packages stored when installed using npm -g command?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am a beginner in node.js and i understand that when we use npm install then a folder node_modules get created and the library/package is stored inside it. But where are the packages stored when the package is installed globally ?

Answer (score 1):

Do `npm list -g` to see the location of the installed libraries and the packages installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, it should be at: `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\xxxx.cmd`

Also, if your open powershell just type `get-command xxxx` It tells you where xxxx command is.